# Trying to redirect in react using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tsx

so I have a bug that I can't seem to solve. Currently I am using react with react router, however I cannot seem to get react to redirect to a page. Here is a expert from my code (keep in mind this is a functional component)

```
<Route path="/login">
  <Login
    onSubmit={(user) => {
      login(user, (status) => {
        if (status == 200) {
          history.push('/home');
        } else {
          history.push('/login');
        }
      });
    }}
  />
</Route>
```

(For reference, I have a login component which takes in a onSubmit callback and in which I call a predefined login method in check the status of the response from my backend and redirect accordingly)

When I run this code and redirect, I get a error that says

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

And just to be clear, I have defined history in the first few lines of my component

```
let history = useHistory();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you created a router? somewhere?

Comment: Yes, this is just a small snippet of my code (the actual code is largely irrelevant to my problem and I did not want to post that much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` is resolving to `undefined` so you are trying to invoke `undefined.push('path')`, hence the error. You need to make `history` accessible within the scope of the component like this:

```js
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => (
const history = useHistory()
return <Login onSubmit={() => history.push('/path')} />
)
```

Comment: This worked for me! I created a useHistory instance in my login component, and passed that to my callback. Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

```
import {  Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

...

<Route path="/login">
  <Login
    onSubmit={(user) => {
      login(user, (status) => {
        if (status == 200) {
           return <Redirect to="/home" />
        } else {
          return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
      });
    }}
  />
</Route>
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried that, but it did not work and Eslint threw errors... I am starting to wonder if I am using the router correctly as all the research I could find tell me to use history.push or the Redirect component. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @AkshatAdsule have you tried passing `Login` Component in ```<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>```

Comment: Would I just pass in component={<Login onSubmit={...}/>}?

Comment: No That would not work     you need to pass your Component in that or you can use `render` option of `route`